# Is this operator trace class?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T:H\to H$ be a compact operator on a complex Hilbert space.
Assume that
$$
\sup_{(e_j)}\sum_j\left|\langle Te_j,e_j\rangle\right|<\infty,
$$
where the supremum extends over all orthonormal bases of $H$.
Does it follow that $T$ is a trace class operator?

Comment: Not only is it true, but you don't need the hypothesis that $T$ is compact---see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036398/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Break the operator into it's real and imaginary parts: $A=\frac{1}{2}(T + T^\dagger)$ and $B=\frac{1}{2i}(T - T^\dagger)$.  These are also compact and satisfy the same estimate.   The estimate, applied to their respective eigenbases, shows that $A$ and $B$ are trace class.  Thus $T=A + i B$ is also trace class.